# Yii- finding whether a value is present based on another value

Tags: php, yii

I'm new to Yii framework. Now, I have a form with two textfields FieldA and FieldB, where I need to check whether the value of FieldB is already there for value of FieldA.
Suppose value of fieldA=123 and value of fieldB=345. If the value of fieldB is repeated for that value of fieldA, then error will be displayed else it should be added to database.
For this I'm taking the count of rows=0 where fieldB=[Value given from the form] and fieldA=[Value given from the form].

```
$b_value=$model->count('FieldB=:FieldB',array(':FieldB'=>$_POST['TableAB']['FieldB']));
```

If the value of $b_value=0 then it return that fieldB is not repeated.
Now, my question is I need to put a condition like-

```
"Select * from table AB where fieldB="$_POST['TableAB']['FieldB']" and fieldA="$_POST['TableAB']['FieldA']"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: $model->count('FieldB=:FieldB AND FieldA = :FieldA',array(':FieldB'=>$_POST['TableAB']['FieldB'], ':FieldA'=>$_POST['TableAB']['FieldA']));     No?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> ```
>  $res = $model->findAll("fieldB= :b AND fieldA=:a", 
>                            array(':b' => $_POST['TableAB']['FieldB'], 
>                                  ':a' => $_POST['TableAB']['FieldA'], ))
> ```

It found all values. If you need the one - use `find()` instead `findAll()`